# Package for Redux/React project package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux

I'm trying to add: https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-url to my react/redux project but I'm not sure what to put for importing.

Is there another, es6 friendly install that I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import isUrl from 'is-url';
```

Or even

```
import anotherNameForIsUrl from 'is-url'
```

The reason for this, is that the module of the library is exported as `default` as seen per the source file: https://github.com/segmentio/is-url/blob/master/index.js which means you are free to give it your own variable name.

Another thing is to think about moving the source code to your project, so you dont need another very small third-party dependency.